# Continuous running Tasks in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

```
private Task<Void> getTransferId = new Task<Void>() {

    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        WebTarget webTarget = client.target(Constants.BASE_URL);
        WebTarget helloworldWebTarget = webTarget.path(Constants.TRANSFER_FILE);
        System.out.println(" checking working.....status");
        Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = helloworldWebTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        PostFileLog fileLog = new PostFileLog();
        fileLog.setSenderId(myUuid);
        fileLog.setReceiverId(clickedPossitionUuid);
        fileLog.setFileName(fileName);
        fileLog.setFileType(fileTypeInt);
        fileLog.setFileSize(fileSizeFinal);
        fileLog.setStatus(Constants.STATUS_PENDING);
        fileLog.setFileDesc(Constants.NO_CAPTION);
        Response response = invocationBuilder.post(Entity.entity(fileLog, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        int status = response.getStatus();
        PostFileLog reponceLog = response.readEntity(PostFileLog.class);
        transferId = reponceLog.getUuid();
        System.out.println(transferId + " fist sending TrasferId andstastus " + status);

        return null;
    }
};
```

For executing the above code I am using `.run();`
it is executing only once. I need to execute this continuously what is the solution for this problem any one can help me?

Comment: "For executing the above code I am using `.run();`". This won't run the task in a background thread: it will run it on the current thread (probably the FX Application Thread, depending on where you call it from). You should either wrap it in a `Thread` and call `start()` on the thread, or submit it to an appropriate `Executor`.

Answer (score -1):

Just put your code in while loop and make the way to stop the while loop

Edited your code check this

```
boolean isStop=false;
private Task getTransferId = new Task()
{

@Override
protected Void call() throws Exception

{
    while(!isStop){
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    WebTarget webTarget = client.target(Constants.BASE_URL);
    WebTarget helloworldWebTarget = webTarget.path(Constants.TRANSFER_FILE);
    System.out.println(" checking working.....status");
    Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = helloworldWebTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    PostFileLog fileLog = new PostFileLog();
    fileLog.setSenderId(myUuid);
    fileLog.setReceiverId(clickedPossitionUuid);
    fileLog.setFileName(fileName);
    fileLog.setFileType(fileTypeInt);
    fileLog.setFileSize(fileSizeFinal);
    fileLog.setStatus(Constants.STATUS_PENDING);
    fileLog.setFileDesc(Constants.NO_CAPTION);
    Response response = invocationBuilder.post(Entity.entity(fileLog, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    int status = response.getStatus();
    PostFileLog reponceLog = response.readEntity(PostFileLog.class);
    transferId = reponceLog.getUuid();
    System.out.println(transferId + " fist sending TrasferId andstastus " + status);
 }
    return null;
}
};

public void StopTask(){//To stop the task
isStop=true;
}
```

Comment: If you use a flag, at least make it volatile. Otherwise the `Task` thread may never see the updated value. However I'd recomend using `cancel`+`isCancelled` instead...